# jQuery: Form Submission - Multiple Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, submit

Currently having some issues with jQuery Form Submissions in my project.

My project contains a general jQuery Code which prevents form double submissions (e.g. someone clicks the 'submit' button multiple times).

```
//prevent multiple form submissions
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function () {
    $(document).on('submit', this, function (e) {
        let $form = $(this);
        if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $form.data('submitted', true);
        }
    });
    return this;
};


$(function () {
    $('form').preventDoubleSubmission();
});
```

This code is included into every single page - so every form should be 'protected'.

For some specific forms I need to check some values before they are submitted - and show a confirm box, if some values are missing (e.g. Are you sure you want to submit this form without value X?)

Here's the code:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="article"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = this;
    let $form = $(form);
    let $category = $form.find('select#article_category'); //get category

    if ($category.length && !$category.val()) { //check if category is selected
        $.confirm({ //jquery confirm plugin
            title: "Are you sure?",
            content: "Value X is missing - continue?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    action: function () {
                        $form.off('submit');
                        form.submit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $form.off('submit');
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

So basically, if the user tries to submit the form, but the value X is missing, there will be a Yes/No Popup first - if the value exists, the form will be submitted right away.

**Problem:**
When I want to submit the form, I call `$form.off('submit');` to remove the event handler and submit afterwards with `form.submit();`. Sadly this also removes my *preventDoubleSubmission* event handler, which allows double submissions again.

Is there a way to fix my issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you include your html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out a relatively ok solution for me. However it is very simple and I might stick with it.

```
//form submission function
function submitForm(form) {
    let $form = $(form);
    let $submit = $form.find('button[type=submit]'); //find submit button

    $submit.attr('disabled', true); //disable button = prevent double submission
    form.submit(); //submit form
}

//submission for every form but not .form-confirm
$(document).on('submit', 'form:not(.form-confirm)', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm(this); //call function
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="article"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = this;
    let $form = $(form);

    let $category = $form.find('select#article_category'); //get category

    if ($category.length && !$category.val()) { //check if category is selected
        $.confirm({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            content: "Value X is missing - continue?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    action: function () {
                        submitForm(form); //call function
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        submitForm(form); //call function
    }
});
```

**So how does it work?**

Basically I just disable the submit button after submitting (=prevent double submissions). I added a class called `form-confirm` to the specific form which the popup should show, so the general rule does not work there.
I always use `preventDefault` and use `form.submit()` to submit right away in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a code snippet with a correct solution. There were multiple issues with your original approach, highlighted below the snippet. Better to run this snippet in a different code playground, where action with javascript work, e.g. JSFiddle.

```js
//prevent multiple form submissions
function submitOnce (e, $form) {
  alert('submitted = ' + $form.data('submitted'));
  if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Double-submission prevented!');
  } else {
    $form.data('submitted', true);
    alert('Double-submission param saved');
  }
}


$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="article"]', function (e) {
  let form = this;
    let $form = $(form);
    
    let $category = $form.find('select#article_category'); //get category

    if ($category.length && !$category.val()) { //check if category is selected
    
      if ( confirm("Are you sure?") ){
        submitOnce(e,$form);
      }
      else {
       e.preventDefault();
      }
        
    } else {
        submitOnce(e,$form);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="article" action="javascript:alert('Form submitted!');">
  <select id="article_category" name="select1">
    <option></option>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

*edit*: adding explanations

`$form.off()` would work if you would bind 'submit' event handler directly on the form element, but in both cases handlers are registered on the document.

Calling `form.submit()` is not necessary, since we are already in a submit handler, hence submit already called. We just need to prevent submissions to continue.

Better is to have just one submit handler, and deal with double submits there.

`e.preventDefault();` has to be just in the else clause for a non-confirmed case and in `submitOnce()`. You had it at the beginning of the main handler, but it was useless there, since `form.submit()` was called again inside, and this call does not prevent the default.

*My approach is not bullet-proof and serves just as a demonstration of what needed to be changed.*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like your explanation - because of that +1, however you solution did not work for me. You use javascript `confirm` which does pause the script until you press yes/no. My `confirm plugin` does not behave like that, meaning that my form is submitted right away, even though my `confirm` shows up. Maybe you can provide an alternative way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a normal span with a click event. Once it is clicked you can disable it (using a class for example) and then submit form. This approach allows you to control form submission without the need of extra coding.

See this example:

```js
$submitBtn = jQuery(".submit");
$form = jQuery("form[name='article']");

$submitBtn.on("click", function() {
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass("disabled"))
    return;

  let $category = $form.find('.name'); //get value

  if ($category.length && !$category.val()) { //check if value is set
    $.confirm({ //jquery confirm plugin
      title: "Are you sure ?",
      content: 'Value x is missing - continue ?',
      buttons: {
        confirm: {
          action: function() {
            $form.submit();
            $submitBtn.addClass("disabled");
          }
        },
        cancel: function() {
          //$.alert('canceled');
        }
      }
    });

    return;
  }

  $submitBtn.addClass("disabled");
  $form.submit();

});
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

form input {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

form .submit {
  padding: 0.3rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

form .submit.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<form action="" name='article'>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="My First Name" class='name'>
  <br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="My Last Name">
  <br><br>
  <span class='submit'>Submit</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That could work as you suggest, however I dont really want to rewrite every single form I have already. Pure JS/jQuery solution would fit my needs better. However great answer. Thank you